# how do I get an enemy to follow me in a 2D platformer Godot

Tags: artificial-intelligence, godot, gdscript

So I'm making a 2D platformer called "**agent 404**". I'm right now making the enemy but can't seem to make it. So I looked for a tutorial but couldn't find any tutorials related to a 2D platformer enemy that follows the player I tried all but most of them but all end up wrong. I want to ask if any of you know a way or a tutorial that could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a tilemap you can use a Navigation2D to do nearly "out-of-the-box" pathfinding.

GDQuest explains some of it in this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fPOt0Jw52s

Since you're making a platformer however, you might run into the same problem where the only tiles with navigation on them are blank and so aren't filled in by the autotiler. If that's the case you can find a workaround here (something I was just stuck on myself :-) ):

[navigation tilemaps without placing walkable tiles manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685183/navigation-tilemaps-without-placing-walkable-tiles-manually/)